# Headless browser testing for heroku

Tags: heroku

Could someone help with the suggestions on how to do headless testing in heroku?

We have developed a script on firefox with opening the browser using selenium.

Is there a way to set any browser options or config to run without headless using the same code with minimal changes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have two options you can use in the browser instead of Firefox : htmlunit and phantomjs.
I use htmlunit and it works great.

Comment: Both htmlunit and phantomjs doesn't works for me except firefox. The webapp developed in ZK framework. HtmlUnit doesn't support all cases where as PhantomJS gives a browser not supported error eventhough the browser is compatible with the given version. HtmlUnit Browser Versions capabilities doesn't support latest versions of firefox. Which version of browser you have used, so that we will use the same version browser and test it........